# geom_segment size argument different behavior for x and y direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm observing different behavior when I use `annotate(geom = "segment")` or `geom_segment` to draw horizontal or vertical lines. I'm looking for a way to get the same width for both lines. Below an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")

# some example graph
g <- ggplot(data = iris, 
            aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Length, 
                group = Species, color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2.5, alpha = .6)

# axes have equal width
g + annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, y = 2, yend = 8) + 
    annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 8, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf)

# x-axes increased in size!
g + annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, y = 2, yend = 8, size = 1) + 
    annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 8, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf, size = 1)
```

The first call to `g + annotate(...` (without the size argument) produces this figure:

[image]

However, the second call (with the size argument) produces this figure:

[image]

Clearly, the width of the x-axis has increased! My question is, how can avoid this in a generic manner (i.e. not by multiplying the x-axis width with 0.7 relative to the y-axis). Any thoughts?

edit:

I'm using ggplot 3.0.0, windows 10, and R 3.5.0

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate this problem – both have the same width for me

Comment: I'm using ggplot2 version 3.0.0 and windows 10. What version/ os are you using?

Comment: R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5. That might be it, although I think the last change to annotation.r was in 2016.

Comment: What does the plot look like if you `ggsave` it to e.g. pdf or png? I see the same issue in RStudio and when using default 'Export / Save as image' there, but the plot looks fine when "`ggsaving`" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue.

But the segment width hasn't actually changed (at least not on mine). What I actually observe is the combined effect of aligning segments to the edges of the plot, and ggplot's default clipping option hiding part of the segments:

```
g2 <- g + 
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf, y = 2, yend = 8, size = 1) + 
  annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 8, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf, size = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") # hide legend as it's not relevant here

# convert to grob & turn off clipping for panel layer
g2.grob <- ggplotGrob(g2)
g2.grob$layout$clip[g2.grob$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g2, g2.grob, nrow = 1)
```

[image: plot]

As the two plots demonstrate, turning off clipping reveals the full width of both segments, which are the same.

(I haven't examined the underlying code sufficiently to answer why the x direction clipped less than the y direction, but this appears to be a fairly niche use case. If your annotated segments were closer to the plot centre rather than smack on its edges, they would have appeared the same size automatically.)

Answer (score 0):

For those it might help, I had the same issue when I used `annotate("segment", ...)` to add a custom y axis to my plot. The y axis was about 2/3 the width of the x axis. I had set the x axis limits using `coord_cartesian()` which defaults to `clip = "on"`, and the width of my custom y axis was getting clipped. Changing to `clip = "off"` fixed it for me.